# Querying data with EF doesn't return all entities

Tags: c#, windows, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I'am currently changing a project from LINQ to SQL to LINQ to Entity. I have the following entity:

```
Customer -> Address
```

I query my database through a WCF Data Service async with this method:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(this DataServiceQuery<TResult> query)
{
    var queryTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<IEnumerable<TResult>>(query.BeginExecute(null, null), (asResult) =>
    {
        var result = query.EndExecute(asResult);
        return result;
    });

    return await queryTask;
}
```

If I do a query on this entity, I can access the Customer, but the address is still null:

```
var query = (DataServiceQuery<Customer>)client.Customer.OrderBy(session => session.LastName);
var data = await query.ExecuteAsync();
Test2.Text = data.LastName(); //returns the lastname
Test2.Text = data.First().Address.Stret; //Address is Null
```

I have checked the database and the foreign keys are set correctly. Why is the address null? Do I have to query another way? In LINQ to SQL it was possible to access the related entity, how can I archive this in LINQ to Entity?

Comment: Perhaps try to use an [`Expand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358709.aspx) call against Address when constructing your query?

Comment: thanks, expand works. If you post a answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nkvu - moving as an answer as indicated by the original poster. Also highly recommend @RAS's answer to this question for an explanation of the different loading strategies.]

Perhaps try to use an [Expand](
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358709.aspx) call against Address when constructing your query to load related entities.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your model. There are three approaches: Explicit Loading, Eager Loading, and Lazy Loading. For eager loading, you have to use `Include`. Or you want to turn on Lazy loading by specifying `Virtual` keyword next to your property and set `LazyLoadingEnabled = true` for your `DataContext`. See more information on loading of related entities here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: +1 for the nice link explaning the technics. On a deeper search I found out that only Egar loading with the Expand functions work on WCF Data-Service.